# Is it possible to make custom "allow" popup in browsers like chrome & firefox?

Tags: javascript, html, css, browser, twilio

I have website that uses Twilio API to make calls. Each time call is made a popup from google chrome comes up saying "http://www.URL.com/ wants to use your microphone. Allow / Deny". On firefox also it comes up in a dialog.

Is it possible to apply CSS to it or somehow customize the way Allow/Deny popup shows up? Or maybe show another custom dialog that has custom buttons of Allow/Deny and when Allow is clicked somehow triggers browser Allow button?

Comment: I seriously doubt it (for security reasons).

Comment: I don't think you can. You can't style and you will always have the browsers popup.

Comment: `#deny { display: none; }` that would be fun.

Answer (score 2):

The whole point of these popups is that the browser is warning the user that the site wants to do something which could have security implications. Being able to modify or supress that popup could stop the user from realising the security implications.

Consider a malicious hacker who wanted to listen in to a user's conversation.

If your request could be done, it would be easy for him to pop up a message saying "This site wants to show you something pretty", instead of "wants to use your microphone". User presses "accept" without realising what's happening, and hacker gets to record all their conversations. Ouch.

The short answer, therefore, is **no, you cannot modify these popups, for security reasons.**

You might be able to convince the user to hit accept and tick the "don't ask me again" box if the browser provides it, but that's as close as you'll get. You definitely will not be able to get rid of the box entirely, nor will you be able to customise it in any way.

It's worth noting that even native apps on mobile devices give you the same kinds of warnings when you install them, so this isn't a browser-specific thing. If you're doing something that the user might possibly have any reason to object to for security or privacy reasons, then the system will warn them before allowing it.