# I want to build custom popups for google chrome's default message like "website wants to know your location"

Tags: angular, google-chrome, notifications

Is it possible to beautify the default notifications like

1. website wants to know your location
2. allow notifications

and similar kind of notifications, my application is built on angular5 & related tech.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/20219986/5043867.